# Dual CPU Socket Motherboard for AMD Phenom II X4

Tags: cpu, motherboard, amd-phenom

I have my eyes on the [AMD Phenom II X4 955 Black Edition Deneb 3.2GHz](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103674) at NewEgg. I want to build me an 8 core machine. Is there any motherboards out there that will take 2 of these AMD beasts? The best thing I can find so far is [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131366), which has only one socket... Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a workstation we are discussing?
Do look up questions like [**CPU Cores: The more the better?**](https://superuser.com/questions/2489/cpu-cores-the-more-the-better/2514#2514) and the likes before you make your call.

Also, take a look at the **Related** questions on this page, right column...

---

Regarding your comment on Nehalem, I have not done an analysis against present AMD platforms,
But you could do that based on my references at
[**Does the Intel i7 offer real improvement over it’s predecessors?**](https://superuser.com/questions/8494/does-the-intel-i7-offer-real-improvement-over-its-predecessors/8495#8495)

I have a feeling it has an advantage over present generation AMD.
But, that is just a feeling, not an analysis.
It would become a very heated and subjective discussion if raised here.

Comment: This is a workstation. In a nutshell, I am looking for the following: 8 cores, 16 GB RAM, 2 x 1TB Mirrored HDD, 2 x 512MB Nvidia Cards, 1 Sound Blaster card

Comment: @Jonas, Right, I thought so. Hope the references help you.

Comment: @nik - I was reading the Jeff Atwood entry on dual core vs. quad core and I was wondering if the data is still relevant since the entry is from 2007. Does Nehalem change the playing field in any way?

Answer (score 5):

IIRC, AM2/AM3 processors are not designed to operate in multiple sockets, so you won't see one.  You might have to go with Opterons for 2-cpu's.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use multiple AMD processors, you need an Opteron that supports [Socket F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_F).

Answer (score 0):

For dual processor setups (dual socket compatible):

- AMD: need to use the Opteron line of processors.
- Intel: need to use the Xeon line of processors.

All the normal desktop processors are intended for single socket setups. Also, the links nik gave you should give you some insight into building such a setup and the pros/cons.