# Quad Core vs 8 Core

Tags: cpu

I am looking at a couple of computers. Both are AMD processor but one has an A8 Quad Core and the other has an FX 8 Core Processor and the rest of the specs are basically the same.

With that said: Am I going to see drastic improvements in speed with 8 cores vs 4? It would seem logical that yes I would BUT at some point you really won't notice the difference between the two.

As part of my question I want to know what are the pro and cons of 8 and 4 core processors.

Note: I do run Adobe Creative Suite (Photoshop, etc) products but I do not do gaming. Please keep this in mind.

Comment: Related (and closed): [Choosing Dual or Quad Core](http://superuser.com/questions/14052/choosing-dual-or-quad-core).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Here is a review which is highly self-explanatory: http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/fx-8150-zambezi-bulldozer-990fx,3043-13.html . You could probably compare the A8 Apu with the i5 2500k, although actually the i5 is 3 times faster than the A8, here is a forum thread between the A8 apu and the i5 2500k: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/313652-10-perormance-core-2500k-3850 . In my opinion I think you should just get the i5 2500k since actually the 2-4 of the 8 cores mostly sleep and only wake up when it gets intense.

Anyway, I hope that I helped :D

**EDIT: Only buy the A8 apu if you do gaming, for productivity go with the i5 2500k over the bulldozer, in addition to that AMD usually also gets up to high temperatures.**

Comment: If you do gaming, you get a separate video card. Those CPU-s with GPU-s in it are still behind low-level graphic cards from AMD/Ati or nvidia, when it comes to intensive graphics. Actually your response is not correct. It's better to get 8 core for the future. The same it was said about quad core. Now quad core is the norm. And you are comparing apples with pears... She said AMD vs AMD.

Comment: I haven't seen heating problem with amd lately.