# Dual CPU Motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

I have two systems with AMD Athlon X2 processors. I need to put both CPU's into one system.
Are there any Dual CPU Motherboards, which i can use?

I'm not so techee, so please be simple in your answers...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/11911/dual-cpu-socket-motherboard-for-amd-phenom-ii-x4 - @hyperslug mentions `AM2/AM3 processors are not designed to operate in multiple sockets, so you won't see one.`

Comment: Also, why do you NEED to put both into one?  It won't just give you twice the speed, you realize...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll answer your question in to sections.

First of all, yes dual CPU motherboards do exist, you can buy them from Newegg.com among other places, look at "motherboards" section and then select the "server motherboards" sub category.

However,

Dual CPU motherboards are usually specialized pieces of hardware aimed at performance critical applications such as a server or high end workstation. They are used when the cutting edge processors are just not enough and you need even more processing power. They also typically only accept server class processors, either Optitron or Xeon processors, not regular desktop processors. Also, the computer operating system must be a business version or higher (ie, windows 7 business or ultimate, windows 7 home premium won't work).

With that being said, as for a typical home user (i don't know what you are, but I'm assuming at least something of this sort by the nature of the question), you are better off buying a brand new computer rather than trying to saving money by trying to combine 2 CPUs into one system. The Athlon X2 processor is an old processor, finding an old dual socket motherboard for them will be extremely difficult and expensive (actually probably doesn't exist as those processors are not server class processors). I suggest that you scrap the old processors and buy yourself a system that uses a Phenom II X4 chip. That will give you plenty more power than a pair of Athlon X2.

Comment: That's [Opteron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opteron), not Optitron.

Comment: is using VirtualBox VM on a dual server motherboard worth it? Can such VM software utilize one full CPU and thus be near-as much performant as if it were running on its own instead of as a guiest OS?